# Fetch result from Many to Many Relation

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two entity with **Many** to **Many** relation like below..

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MEMBER")
public class Member implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SELECT)
    @JoinTable(name = "MEMBER_BADGE",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "member_id", referencedColumnName = "id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "badge_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
    private List<Badge> badgeList = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // Getter & Setters

}
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BADGE")
public class Badge implements Serializable{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "badgeList")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Member> memberList = new ArrayList<>(0);

    // Getter & Setters
}
```

`Badge` name examples... "**Teacher**", "**Doctor**", "**Engineer**" etc.

How to get all the "**`List<Member>`**" who have "**Teacher**" badge by Hibernate `Criteria/Query`.

`session.createCriteria(Member.class).add(Restrictions.eq(---What ?---)).list();`

`session.createQuery("select mem from Member where ???? ").list();`

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved using alias like...

```
session.createCriteria(Member.class)
       .createAlias("badgeList", "badge")
       .add(Restrictions.eq("badge.name", "Teacher"))
       .list();
```